# Why my PNG image on website is inverted on color?

Tags: html, css

Why is the red color on my website appearing inverted when I host it online, while the other images display correctly? I've inspected that a new background-image of base64 is being applied on top of the CSS, but I don't understand why this is happening.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>The Simons Game</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="shortcut icon"
      href="Game_Button/Yellow_button.png"
      type="image/x-icon" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65"
      crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rye&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Body heading -->
    <h1 id="header">The Simons Game</h1>
    <h2 id="title">Press any key to start</h2>
    <!-- font size is added for removing space between buttons -->
    <!-- Buttons section -->
    <div class="contain" style="font-size: 0">
      <div type="button" id="red" class="press butn red"></div>
      <div type="button" id="blue" class="press butn blue"></div>
      <div type="button" id="green" class="press butn green"></div>
      <div type="button" id="yellow" class="press butn yellow"></div>
    </div>
    <h2 id="highscore">Highscore 0</h2>

    <input
    type="button"
    id="Soundcontroller"
    value="music"
    onclick="togglePlay(),textchange()" />
    <audio id="myAudio" src="neon-gaming-128925.mp3" loop autoplay  ></audio>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "carnival";
  src: url(Fonts/Carnevalee\ Freakshow.ttf);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "railroad";
  src: url(Fonts/IFC\ RAILROAD\ 2.ttf);
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url(newbg.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

#header {
  padding: 1%;
  font-size: 6rem;
  font-family: "carnival", cursive;
  color: #f49d1a;
  text-shadow: #9a5d02 6px 4px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-family: "railroad", cursive;
  color: #f49d1a;
  text-shadow: #9a5d02 4px 3px;
}

#title {
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

/* Game over Flash Screen */
.game-over {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

/* Button Container Styling */
.press {
  outline: none;
  width: 230px;
  height: 235px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2%;
  margin: 20px;
}

/* Glow Buttons */
.redglow {
  background-image: url(Game_Button/Red_button_glow.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.blueglow {
  background-image: url(Game_Button/Blue_button_glow.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.greenglow {
  background-image: url(Game_Button/Green_button_glow.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.yellowglow {
  background-image: url(Game_Button/Yellow_button_glow.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* Normal Buttons */
.red {
  background-image: url(Game_Button/Red_button.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.blue {
  background-image: url(Game_Button/Blue_button.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.green {
  background-image: url(Game_Button/Green_button.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.yellow {
  background-image: url(Game_Button/Yellow_button.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* audio buttons */
#Soundcontroller {
  font-family: "railroad", cursive;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: #f49d1a;
  text-shadow: #9a5d02 3px 2px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  /* top: 20px; */
  /* left: 100px; */
  text-align: right;
  left: 2%;
  top: 2%;
}
```

[It is apperaing like this after hosting it on Github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCluO.jpg)
[on my local server as i am expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfU5X.jpg)]

Comment: Please create a [**Minimal** reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Found his github (https://github.com/Knoxzen/The_Simons_Game)
This is not reproductible, make sure you have refresh your browser cache...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a dark reader extension of chrome, which made colours look inverted.
After disabling the extension every thing worked fine.

Comment: mark as correct or close it please.